# Forbidden Error in ajax call with wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I'm getting 403 error in my plugin develop when I try to use ajax calls. I had disabled all plugins and activated default theme, no works. I have no cache plugin, and I have no server cache.

I get:
403
Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied!

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_actualizar_jornada', 'actualizar_jornada' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_actualizar_jornada', 'actualizar_jornada');

    function actualizar_jornada() {
        $postdata = $_POST;
    
    
        echo $postdata;
    
        wp_die();
    }
```

LOCALIZATION SCRIPT

```
wp_register_script('lmfront-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../includes/js/lmfront.js');
wp_localize_script('lmfront-js', 'strings', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'lstJugadoresParticipantesPlaceholder' => __('Find Players', 'leaguemanagement'),
    'lstEquiposTeamsPlaceholder' => __('Find Teams', 'leaguemanagement'),
));
wp_enqueue_script('lmfront-js');
```

JS

```
$('.btn-update-jornada').on('click', function(){
    var idjornada = parseInt($(this).data('idjornada'));
    var data = {
        'action': 'actualizar_jornada',
        'idjornada': idjornada,
        'marcador_local': parseInt($('#resultado-local-' + idjornada).val()),
        'marcador_visitante': parseInt($('#resultado-visitante-' + idjornada).val()),
    };
    
    $.ajax({
       type : "post",
       url : strings.ajaxurl,
       data : data,
       error: function(response){
           console.error(response);
       },
       failure: function(response){
           console.error(response);
       },
       success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this error occur! you may follow [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/) Or you can review your code in following steps:

Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_ajax_{action_name}` `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action_name}` in your plugin file. Suppose my plugin name is `test-plugin` and my main plugin file name is `test-plugin.php`

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Plugin
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org
Description: This just a test plugin.
Author: Razon
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://raazon.github.io/
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_docs_enqueue_scripts');
function wp_docs_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'scripts.js', ['jquery']);
    wp_localize_script('scripts', 'ajax_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'lstJugadoresParticipantesPlaceholder' => __('Find Players', 'leaguemanagement'),
        'lstEquiposTeamsPlaceholder' => __('Find Teams', 'leaguemanagement'),
    ));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_actualizar_jornada', 'actualizar_jornada');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_actualizar_jornada', 'actualizar_jornada');
function actualizar_jornada()
{
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    echo $id;
    wp_die();
}
```

And my `JS` file scripts.js

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'actualizar_jornada',
                id: 100,
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('Sending request...');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (errorThrown, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have tested this in my local and work properly. If this code not work in your end then there are other issue in in your website / host